# WebApp configuration in mod_perl 2 environment

Tags: perl, configuration-files, mod-perl2

I have a web app I'm writing in mod_perl 2.  (It's a custom handler module, not registry or perlrun scripts.)  There are several configuration options I'd like to have set at server initialization, preferably from a configuration file.  The problem I'm having is that I haven't found a good place to pass a filename for my app's config file.

I first tried loading "./app.conf" but the current directory isn't the location of the modules, so it's unpredictable and error-prone.  Or, I have to assume some path -- relative or absolute.  This is inflexible and could be problematic if the host OS distribution is changed.  I don't want to hard-code a path (though, something in /etc may be acceptable if there's just no better way).

I also tried PerlSetVar, but the value isn't available until request time.  While this is workable, it means I'm potentially reading a config file from disk at least once per child (thread) init.  I would rather load at server init and have an immutable static hash that is part of the spawned environment when a child is created.

I considered using a config.pl, but this means I either have a config.pl with one option to configure where to find the app.conf file, or I move the options themselves into config.pl and require end-users to respect Perl syntax when setting options.  Future users will be internal admins, so that's not unreasonable, but it's more complicated than I'd like.

So what am I missing?  Any good alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Usually a top priority is to avoid having configuration files amongst your executables.  Otherwise a server misconfiguration could accidentally show your private configuration info to the world.  I put everything the app needs under `/srv/app0`, with subdir `cfg` which is a sibling to the dirs containing executables.  ([More detail.](http://larig.wordpress.com/2010/06/16/layout-for-a-cgiapplication/))

If you're pre-loading modules via `PerlPostConfigRequire startup.pl` to access `mod/startup.pl` then that's the best place to put the configuration file location `../cfg/app.cnf` and you have complete flexibility re how to store the configuration in memory.  An alternative is to `PerlModule` your modules and load the configuration (with a relative path as above) in a `BEGIN` block within one of them.

Usually processing a configuration file doesn't take appreciable time, so a popular option is to lazy-load: if the code detects the configuration is missing it loads it before continuing.  That's no use if the code needed to know the configuration earlier than that, but it avoids lots of problems, especially when migrating code to a non-modperl env.